# Python reference count to object field

Tags: python, garbage-collection

The following code is run on Mac terminal on Python3:

```
import gc

import numpy as np

class D(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = np.arange(3)

    def get(self):
        return self.value


d = D()
print(gc.get_referrers(d))
print(type(gc.get_referrers(d)))
print()
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d)))
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d.value)))
print()

l = []
l.append(d)
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d)))
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d.value)))
print()

x = d.value
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d)))
print(len(gc.get_referrers(d.value)))
```

The above code will return:

```
[{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10de6cef0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test3.py', '__cached__': None, 'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>, 'np': <module 'numpy' from '/Users/jkim/Codes/Codes/Notebooks/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>, 'D': <class '__main__.D'>, 'd': <__main__.D object at 0x10dec7fd0>}]
<class 'list'>

1
0

2
0

2
1
```

Could anyone explain to me:

1. Why is reference count to `d.value` `0`, and if the reference count to `d.value` is indeed `0`, why is `d.value` not getting garbage collected by Python?
2. What exactly is the list that the object `d` is being referred by?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you subclassing `object`? Is this Python 2? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: This is python3. I did it out of force of habit. Thank you for the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reference count is **not** 0. You cannot observe an object with a 0 reference count in CPython; you need a reference to an object to do anything with it, and that reference will count toward its reference count. What you're seeing is that there are no **GC-tracked referrers** for the object. If you want the actual reference count, use `sys.getrefcount`.
2. There is no list with a reference to the object. You're taking the type of the list of referrers returned by `gc.get_referrers`. This list is not itself a referrer of the object.

`d.value` has no GC-tracked referrers for the following reason. First, `d.value` is a NumPy array with a dtype that cannot hold object references, so it cannot participate in a reference cycle. The NumPy implementation optimizes such arrays by making them GC-untracked.

Second, the only references to `d.value` are one reference in `d.__dict__`, and the temporary references created when you access `d.value` or pass it to `gc.get_referrers`. The temporary references live in the current stack frame's bytecode operand stack, or in C local variables, and those locations aren't visible to the GC. `d.__dict__` has only ever held objects that cannot be GC-tracked (the array and the `'value'` string), and the CPython dict implementation does not GC-track a dict until a key or value is inserted that is capable of being GC-tracked (or in some cases when a dict is created as a copy of a tracked dict).